# Set half of the filters of a layer as not trainable keras/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a model suggested by [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1705/1705.04748.pdf) research paper where I set half of the filters of a convolution layer to Gabor filters and the rest are random weights which are initialized by default. Normally, if I have to set a layer as not trainable, I set the `trainable` attribute as `False`. But here I have to freeze only half of the filters of a layer and I have no idea how to do so. Any help would be really appreciated. I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend.

Comment: Do you want to freeze random 50 percent or specific ones of specific layers?

Comment: I want to freeze the gabor filters and set the default initialised weights as trainable.

Comment: You can freeze Convolutional filters layer-wise in Keras. Refer to the following SO query for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178499/specify-some-untrainable-filters-for-keras-convolutional-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making two convolutional layers which are getting the same input and (nearly) the same parameters? So one of them is trainable wir random weights at initialization and the other layer is non trainable with the gabor filters.

You could then merge the outputs of the two layers together in a way that it looks like it's the output from one convolutional network.

Here is an example for demonstration (you need to use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)):

```
n_filters = 32

my_input = Input(shape=...)
conv_freezed = Conv2D(n_filters/2, (3,3), ...)
conv_trainable = Conv2D(n_filters/2, (3,3), ...)

conv_freezed_out = conv_freezed(my_input)
conv_trainable_out = conv_trainable(my_input)
conv_out = concatenate([conv_freezed_out, conv_trainable_out])

# set weights and freeze the layer
conv_freezed.set_weights(...)
conv_freezed.trainable = False
```

Comment: That's right! I just edited your answer and added an example to help others better understand this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dennis-ec and @today! Note for other newbies like me: use the keras functional api to create layers with this kind of logic since it's not possible in sequential.

Comment: For those who have found this in 2021 or later, this is possible now with Keras classes (as opposed to just the functional api); however, it may not be the preferred method. It isn't possible with sequential models by the inherent nature of what Sequential means, and with Keras.layers, this requires two separate layers to be concatenated making it the graph branch. This could still be included in a sequential model if a custom layer was made this way.