# Specific Dropout in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I would like to train an autoencoder by using only specific PARTS of a layer (the layer named FEATURES in the autoencoder example at the bottom of this question).

In my case, NOK pictures for a new product are very rare, but needed for training. The aim is generate NOK pictures from OK pictures (all examples I found did the opposite). The idea is to force learning OK-picture structure in features[0:n-x] and learning NOK-picture structure (maybe from a similiar product) in features[n-x:n] in order to use the NOK-features as parameters to generate NOK-pictures from OK-pictures.

Two ideas came to my mind using a non-random dropout

`(1)` `keras.layers.Dropout(rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None)` has the noise_shape argument, but I am not sure if it helps me as it only describes the shape. It would be perfect to be able to provide a mask consisting of {0,1} to apply on the layer in order to switch on/off specific nodes

`(2)` creating a custom layer (named MaskLayer below) which performs masking specific nodes of the layer e.g. as a tuple of {0,1}.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418749/set-half-of-the-filters-of-a-layer-as-not-trainable-keras-tensorflow), but I do not think it applies (generate a layer by concatenating layers which can be freezed separately).

```py
def autoEncGenerate0( imgSizeX=28, imgSizeY=28, imgDepth=1):  ####:
    ''' keras blog autoencoder'''
    input_img = Input(shape=(imgSizeX, imgSizeY, imgDepth)) 
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = MaxPooling2D((4, 4), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded0 = MaxPooling2D((8, 8), padding='same', name="FEATURES")(x) 
    encoded1 = MaskLayer(mask)(encoded0) # TO BE DONE (B2) masking layer parts
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded1)
    x = UpSampling2D((8, 8))(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((4, 4))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D( imgDepth, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    return( autoencoder)
```

Thanks for hints.

Comment: The layer you specified is a maxpooling layer. As far as I'm aware, these do not get trained but are just an operator on the previous layer. Can you specify what you are trying to do?
Secondly, it appears from the dropout documentation that you cannot set a specific pattern to a dropout layer, only a seed, which gives no guarantee of which areas/features are then dropped out.

Answer (score 0):

There is `trainable` attribute that each instance of `tf.keras.layer.Layer` has which disables training of the variables of that layer. `UpSampling2D` doesn't have any variables so you CAN'T train it. What you want is to train the variables of the convolutional layer that comes before that upsampling layer.

You could do it like this:

```py
# define architecture here
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
layers_names = [l.name for l in autoencoder.layers]
trainable_layer_index = layers_names.index('FEATURES') - 1
for i in range(len(autoencoder.layers)):
    if i != trainable_layer_index:
        autoencoder.layers[i].trainable = False
# compile here
```

NOTE that you compile the model AFTER you set layers to trainable/non-trainable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I am aware of freezing a complete layer (should have written that). The idea is to force the model to learn/use only a PART of one layer information.